# ::part() pseudo-element not a valid pseudo element in Blazor server project

Tags: css, css-selectors, blazor, pseudo-element, visual-studio-2022

I can't seem to find anything on here about this issue I'm having. I've read quite a bit about the ::part() pseudo-element, which represents any element within a shadow tree that has a matching part attribute. I want to style parts of the Ignite UI dockmanager by Infragistics, and the CSS is correctly merged as directly styling the body works fine, but when I want to style its parts, it shows that the ::part() pseudo-element is not a valid pseudo element. Granted, I'm fairly new to styling shadow dom, but intellisense recognizes many other elements and not ::part(). Is there a step I'm missing?

[image: pseudo-element ::part invalid]

Comment: Seems like a VS feedback issue really

Comment: @MisterMagoo, you're probably right. I'm going to test it with VS 2019 now (currently on 2022).

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

::part() is not all that new, having appeared in its FPWD back in 2018 and its ED last updated in 2020 but still actively worked on. If VS2022's IntelliSense recognizes more modern features I would suggest filing an issue. Otherwise, I would suggest turning off IntelliSense for CSS entirely as I generally don't recommend using Visual Studio's built-in CSS validation.

Comment: Thanks! I did, and in the meantime I manually added ::part() to the css pseudo-element selectors xml file. It actually turns out the element worked fine all along, and that I needed to download a js bundle file that would unpack the shadow dom. This was casually missing from the Ignite UI Blazor page styling set up, and I found it in one of their github samples, which I alerted them to.